# package XML is missing @AzurePipeline ant

Tags: xml, ant, azure-devops, salesforce, azure-pipelines

so I am quite experienced with running ant manually and migrating  Salesforce metadata.

Now we are trying to create our CLI solution using Azure Devops. So far we have a repository and a pipeline that uses ant. I was following the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPGaVO72I1s .I would think there is no need to provide a package.xml file since this is the reason of CLI: to build automatically so why would one create the package manually? Also there is no package.xml in the linked video.

When I run it I got two errors:

**ll Component Failures:
1.  package.xml -- Error: No package.xml found
*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED *************

also

[antlib:com.salesforce] Could not load definitions from resource com/salesforce/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

I am totally confused now - why it is seeking for a package xml anyway?
here it is:

```
<project name="deployTest" default="deployCode" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ant.jar" value="ant-salesforce.jar" />
    <property name="sf.password" value="${salesforce.password}" />
    <property name="sf.username" value="${salesforce.username}" />
    <property name="sf.serverurl" value="${salesforce.serverurl}" />

    <target name="retrieveCode">
       <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="src" unpackaged="package/package.xml"/>
    </target>

    enter code here

    <path id="classpath">
      <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml"
        uri="antlib:com.salesforce" >
        <classpath>
          <pathelement location ="${ant.jar}" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <target name="deployCode">
        <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployroot="." checkonly="true"></sf:deploy>

    </target>
</project>
```

Any ideas are really welcome!

Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to deploy via the Metadata API, you need a `package.xml` manifest -- full stop. This has nothing to do with your CI system (Azure DevOps) per se; it's required by the Salesforce platform APIs, and therefore by those tools, including Ant, that are clients of the Metadata API.

The only situations where you don't need a `package.xml` are if you're pushing Salesforce DX source code (via, for example, `sfdx force:source:push` to a scratch org), or if you're using a build tool that generates or refreshes `package.xml` automatically from your source directory. [CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/) (Salesforce.org's free, open source build tool) can update `package.xml` for you automatically. (Disclaimer: I'm on the team that builds CumulusCI).